# How to check if a javascript function exists from silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How to check if a javascript function exists from silverlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your silverlight code you check for the presence of anything including a function a with the `GetProperty` method:-

```
 var fn = HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("myJavascriptFunction");
 if (fn != null)
     fn.InvokeSelf("Hello");
```

On caveat though, if the name exists but it isn't a function the above code will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTML Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28VS.95%29.aspx).

If you call `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke();` on a javascript method that is not present, the Invoke() call should throw an exception.